# The type or namespace name 'YourDbContext' could not be found for selected drop down in MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

[image]

In mvc 5 i used selected dropdown but it shows** it
**

*it says*

> The type or namespace name 'YourDbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?

``How can be fixed it`[tag:YourDbContext]`

Comment: You have an EDMX File. Normally you would have a Context called "EmployeeEntities" or something like that. The name can be found in the edmx and icluded items underneath.

Comment: Need more detail and clarity